# Why frequent inflight directions to Sachs Harbour and Eureka?

Tags: air-travel, maps, in-flight-services

I was recently on a Royal Jordanian flight from Hong Kong to Bangkok. The inflight airshow cycled through the usual screens - total flight, day/night, stats of the flight, direction of Mecca, etc etc.

One screen I could not get my head around, for the entire flight we were regularly updated about the distance to Sachs Harbour and Eureka:

[image: Screen]

Why?

Comment: My guess is that this is a bug in the software running on Royal Jordanian's systems, and that it should be pointing you towards nearer settlements.  But it'll be practically impossible to confirm this definitively unless someone who works for Royal Jordanian's software contractor happens by.

Comment: I would suspect an easter egg. A programmer who worked on it was from one or both towns or liked a tv show set there or something.

Comment: Based on distance, I would think that the "Eureka" is the one in Nunavut, Canada, but the direction does not seem correct for either (should be 3° for Eureka and 15° for Sachs Harbour, not roughly 50° as the maps seems to indicate). Both places are pretty isolated quite far North. Maybe it was just an error entering the codes (YSY for Sach Harbour and YEU for Eureka) instead of the intended landmarks?

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical reason for it: its either a bug or an easter egg of some sort. In-flight entertainment systems are not exactly known for their excellent operation.